# Azure CORS Configuration

Tags: jquery, azure, cors, azure-blob-storage, fine-uploader

I am using the azure.jquery.fineuplaoder-4.4.0 source and am getting these errors when I try to upload:

```
OPTIONS http://gfbc.blob.core.windows.net/beta 403 (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.) 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gfbc.blob.core.windows.net/beta. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.gfbclife.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using the default html template that is provided and calling FineUploader like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: 'http://gfbc.blob.core.windows.net/beta'
            },
            signature: {
                endpoint: '/Signature'
            },
            retry: {
                enableAuto: true
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have defined my CORS rule as:

```
Allowed Origin: http://dev.gfbclife.org
Allowed Methods: Get, head, Post, Put, Delete, trace, Options
Allowed Headers: *
Exposed Headers: *
Max Age: 432000
```

UPDATE: I have corrected the CORS rule and no longer get the previous errors. I am now  getting these errors:

```
POST http://gfbc.blob.core.windows.net/beta 405 (The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.) 
[Fine Uploader 4.4.0] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token <)
```

The response from the POST is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>UnsupportedHttpVerb</Code>
<Message>The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.
RequestId:f24c6afb-6e42-42da-aafb-3151422562cc
Time:2014-05-21T02:26:50.2758734Z</Message></Error>
```

Comment: The URL in your `Allowed Origin` does not look right. Can you please confirm that it is the correct URL from where the requests are being originated?

Comment: I have updated the question now, it has been using http://dev.gfbclife.org

Comment: I was able to get it working with `Allowed Origin: *`, but I would prefer not to leave it wide open.

Comment: The origin URL must match exactly with what's configured in CORS rule including the casing. Can you please check if that's not the case?

Comment: I have updated the question with the latest error.

Comment: Uploading blob is a `PUT` operation. I have not worked with the fineuploader plugin so I'm not sure if it uses `POST` by default. You may want to change the verb to `PUT` if it supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, your CORS rules are incorrect.  Your allowed origins must include the domain of the URL you provided for the `request.endpoint` option.

Comment: I have updates the CORS entry and I no longer get that error.

Comment: Your latest error is due to improper initialization of the library.  If you are using the jQuery plug-in wrapper, you must init the plug-in using `$("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderAzure({...`.  You can read more about proper use of the Azure endpoint handler in the [getting started guide](http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/01-getting-started.html).

Comment: Great, it's working now! Is it possible to preserve the original filename on the upload?

Comment: Yes, set the [`blobProperties.blobName` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-azure.html#blobProperties.blobName) to "filename".