# fine-uploader azure originator in request instead of endpoint

Tags: javascript, azure, fine-uploader

I am attempting to put blobs to azure storage  and I believe I have the server side sas and azure CORS set up correctly.
In my html I have
`var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer'
            },
            signature: {
                endpoint: 'https://myserver/sas/'
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: '/success'
            },
            retry: {
               enableAuto: true
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true
            },
            cors: {
                expected: true,
                sendCredentials:  true,
            },`

In debug mode I see fine-uploader azure gets the sas correctly and then attempts to send the put request but instead of going to the azure endpoint as entered, it attempts to send it to the host as per this message.
Request URL:https://myhostsite/project/sr=c&sp=w&sig=Vh/QLKT3xhkbGBsiUAk4U1eEFpAcD87OK9%2BqgGd8cO4%3D&sv=2016-05-31&se=2017-04-26T22%3A34%3A57Z
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 0):

Have you permitted PUT request in **AllowedMethods** while you set **CORS** rules?

[image]

I took your code with `Fine Uploader 5.14.2` to upload an image file to Azure storage. It works fine on my site.

[image]

And here is a similar question from SO: [Azure CORS Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772566/azure-cors-configuration)

Comment: Thank you for the response and taking the time.  I am embarrassed to say I misunderstood fine-uploader documentation and on the SAS return I only included the SAS and not the full SAS_URL.  This caused the put request to go to the host instead of my azure storage.  Works great now.