# Azure Storage File Storage, upload file From JavaScript at share level not account?

Tags: javascript, file, azure, upload

Is it possible to add file to Azure Storage file with SAS token from file share level only 
?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a SAS Token only for a particular share and not for the whole account?

Comment: I can create token ,how to use it from JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good Javascript library called [Fine Uploader](https://fineuploader.com/) which could be used for uploads directly to Azure from the browser.

Example:

```
if (qq.supportedFeatures.ajaxUploading) {
    var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://{ YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }.blob.core.windows.net/{ YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME }'
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '/signature'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/success'
        }
    });
}
```

You can generate a full SAS URL in your backend then expose it as the web API which could be set into the **endpoint** of the **signature** option.

For more details, please refer to [Setting Fine Uploader Options](https://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/02-setting_options-azure.html) and [fine-uploader azure originator in request instead of endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645741/fine-uploader-azure-originator-in-request-instead-of-endpoint).